# Code only works in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

Anybody know why my code only displays properly in Chrome, and not in Firefox or ie. The main problem is with the " Roman style columns ". I'm a stoopid noob so please answer as simply as possible.   Is there a way to resolve this by adding vendor prefixes ? Stack overflow is now telling me to add more details, before I can  ask this question. So the more details is, that after 5 months of hard work trying to learn how to code. I am ready to quit, If I can not solve this problem. I hope it is ok to use the word "problem" here, because I already learned that it is not allowed in the title of a question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main3.css">

<title>Chemas Website</title>

</head>

<body>

<header class= "mh-container">
<div class= "h-container">

<h1>José María Penabad B.</h1>

<h2 id="Abo">Abogado</h2>

<h2 id="Att">Attorney at Law</h2>

<h2 id="San">San Jose, Costa Rica</h2>

<h2 id="email">jpenabad@racsa.co.cr</h2>

<div id="scales1">
<img src="imagesC/scales1.png" alt="scales of justice" height="140" width="140">
</div>

<div id="scales2">
<img src="imagesC/scales2.png" alt="scales of justice" height="140" width="140">
</div>

<div id="flag1">
<img class="f1radius" src="imagesC/flag1.png" alt="flag" height="40" width="70">
</div>

<div id="flag2">
<img class="f2radius" src="imagesC/flag2.png" alt="flag" height="40" width="70">
</div>

</div><!--close h-container-->

</header>


<!--Roman Columns-->
<div class="content"> 

<div id="col_topleft">
<img src="imagesC/col_topleft.png" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_topright">
<img src="imagesC/col_topright.png" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_bottleft">
<img src="imagesC/col_bottleft.png" alt="column" height="596" width="60">
</div>

<div id="col_bottright">
<img src="imagesC/col_bottright.png" alt="column" height="596" width="60">
</div>

<div id="scroll1">
<img  src="imagesC/scroll1.png" alt="scroll" height="80" width="700">
</div>

<div id="scroll2">
<img class="radius" src="imagesC/scroll2.png" alt="scroll" height="80" width="385">
</div>

<h3 class=toph3>Please Allow Me To Introduce Myself.</br>I'm a man of wealth and taste !</h3>

<p class="p1and2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, inventore, natus obcaecati debitis facilis quos ipsum libero quidem voluptatum tenetur laboriosam perspiciatis! Unde optio aliquid cum alias similique nobis cupiditate.
Temporibus, itaque, nobis, quaerat omnis amet ipsam provident sed ea incidunt minus consectetur corporis. Aliquam, excepturi ipsum similique ad tenetur quas labore ipsam cupiditate dolorem odit inventore laborum ea. Ut!
</p>

<p class="p1and2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, et saepe. Exercitationem, perferendis, nemo quo itaque unde vel consectetur est sequi recusandae eum cum assumenda non sapiente excepturi quas odio.
Sit, alias, ea quibusdam adipisci aperiam officia a aliquam dolorum id culpa animi distinctio nisi voluptates repellat vel? Debitis, praesentium recusandae iusto a quis ducimus libero voluptates porro aperiam earum.
</p>

<h3 class=both3>Beinvenido !</h3>


<p class="p3">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, et dolorem cumque odit maxime unde sapiente nesciunt in quo vitae temporibus consequuntur voluptas dolor ipsum repellendus alias nam quia at?
Ratione, at, sed, quisquam, repellat reiciendis laudantium consequatur molestiae adipisci vero tempora ab saepe iste doloribus ad earum rem mollitia quidem soluta laborum magni! Excepturi enim qui odio ut rerum.
</p>

<p class="p4">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, et dolorem cumque odit maxime unde sapiente nesciunt in quo vitae temporibus consequuntur voluptas dolor ipsum repellendus alias nam quia at?
Ratione, at, sed, quisquam, repellat reiciendis laudantium consequatur molestiae adipisci vero tempora ab saepe iste doloribus ad earum rem mollitia quidem soluta laborum magni! Excepturi enim qui odio ut rerum.
</p>

</div><!--close content div-->

<div>
<footer>

<p class="ftr"><strong>Copyright 2017 &copy; All Rights Reserved</strong></p>

<div>
<img src="imagesC/ALMA.png" alt="ALMA" height="22" width="220" class="center"/>
</div>

</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>                   






*{margin:0 ;
  padding: 0;
}

.mh-container{max-width: 100%;
height: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
/* border: 2px solid red;*/
background: #fff;
background: radial-gradient(#000000,#2a2a2a,#565656,#828282,#a7a7a7,#d7d7d7);
}            

h1 {text-align: center;
color:#c8e1e1;
text-shadow:
-1px -1px 0 #000,
1px -1px 0 #000,
-1px 1px 0 #000,
1px 1px 0 #000;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#Abo {text-align: center;
color: #c8e1e1;
padding-top: 0px;
}   

#Att {text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
color: #c8e1e1;
}

#San {text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
color: #c8e1e1;
}

#email {text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
color: #c8e1e1;
text-shadow:
-1px -1px 0 #000,
1px -1px 0 #000,
-1px 1px 0 #000,
1px 1px 0 #000;
}

#scales1 {position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 120px;
border: 3px solid red;
height: 140px;
border-radius: 70px;
}

#scales2 {position: absolute;
top: 25px;
right: 120px;
border: 3px solid red;
height: 140px;
border-radius: 70px;
}

#flag1 {position: absolute;
top:0px;
}     

#flag2 {position: absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
}     

.f1radius {border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;}  
.f2radius {border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;}

body {background: linear-gradient(#000000,#2A2A2A,#565656,#828282,#A7A7A7);
}      

#scroll1 {position: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 190px;
}

#scroll2 {position: absolute;
top: 1183px;
left: 350px;
}

.radius{border-top-left-radius: 8px;    
border-top-right-radius: 8px;}  

/*Roman Columns*/
#col_topleft {position: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 25px;
 }       
#col_topright {position: absolute;
top: 250px;
right: 25px;
 }       
#col_bottleft {position: absolute;
top: 670px;
left: 25px;
 }       
#col_bottright {position: absolute;
top: 670px;
right: 25px;
 }       

.toph3 {text-align: center;
padding-top: 200px;
color: #c8e1e1 ;
font-family: sans-serif;}

.both3 {text-align: center;
padding-top: 60px;
color: #c8e1e1;
font-family: sans-serif;}

p{margin-left: 150px;
margin-right: 150px;
margin-top: 60px;
text-indent:20px;    
font-family: sans-serif;
}

.p1and2 {color: #c8e1e1;}

.p3 {color: #c8e1e1;}

.p4 {color: #c8e1e1;
margin-bottom: 80px;}

footer {width: 100%;
min-height: 80px;
background-color: black
}

.ftr {text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
color: #c8e1e1;
}     

img.center{display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I moved your css into style tags and it looks the same across the 3 browsers. What exactly is the problem? If you can post a screen shot or explain whats not working I will fix it for you.

Comment: @Benr89  Thanks for your help. The problem I'm having is that when I run it in Firefox, the Roman style columns on each side of the page don't reach all the way to top of the footer.    And in ie, parts of them are missing all together.      Like I said I am a noob, and I don't know about style tags. But I will do some research and try to add them and see what happens.

Comment: @Benr89 I'm still not having any luck. Is there any way you could show me the changes you made to my code, that made it look the same across the 3 browsers ?

Comment: if you want people to solve this, you need to include a complete example. in this case, you need a zipfile with the html file and the referenced image assets. Without this, there is no way for people to reproduce your problem and help fix it. It would also help if you posted a screenshot of what you want it to look like, and what you actually see on Firefox.

Comment: Further, the best way to get help on Stack Overflow is to post a Minimal example. This means stripping all unnecessary stuff out of your page, and showing just the minimal example, and then titling it correctly. (such as: cross-browser way to make images vertically stretch to fit content)

Comment: @ David Jeske  Thanks for the tips. The only information I could find regarding screen shots said that I was not allowed to do that as I have a reputation of less than 10. After posting this question under a different title, with just a portion of the code, and not getting any answers that solved the problem, another user suggested that I post all my code as something else may be the cause pf the problem. He has generously offered to actually help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so I moved your code inside the style tags and changed some the image files because I obviously cant see the ones that you were referencing.

Code is below, as is screenshots from chrome, ie and firefox.

All seem to be behaving the same in regards to to the columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main3.css">

    <title>Chemas Website</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .mh-container {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /* border: 2px solid red;*/
            background: #fff;
            background: radial-gradient(#000000,#2a2a2a,#565656,#828282,#a7a7a7,#d7d7d7);
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #c8e1e1;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }

        #Abo {
            text-align: center;
            color: #c8e1e1;
            padding-top: 0px;
        }

        #Att {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 5px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
        }

        #San {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 5px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
        }

        #email {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 5px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
            text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
        }

        #scales1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            left: 120px;
            border: 3px solid red;
            height: 140px;
            border-radius: 70px;
        }

        #scales2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            right: 120px;
            border: 3px solid red;
            height: 140px;
            border-radius: 70px;
        }

        #flag1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
        }

        #flag2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
        }

        .f1radius {
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        }

        .f2radius {
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        }

        body {
            background: linear-gradient(#000000,#2A2A2A,#565656,#828282,#A7A7A7);
        }

        #scroll1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 250px;
            left: 190px;
        }

        #scroll2 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 1183px;
            left: 350px;
        }

        .radius {
            border-top-left-radius: 8px;
            border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        }

        /*Roman Columns*/
        #col_topleft {
            position: absolute;
            top: 250px;
            left: 25px;
        }

        #col_topright {
            position: absolute;
            top: 250px;
            right: 25px;
        }

        #col_bottleft {
            position: absolute;
            top: 670px;
            left: 25px;
        }

        #col_bottright {
            position: absolute;
            top: 670px;
            right: 25px;
        }

        .toph3 {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 200px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .both3 {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 60px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        p {
            margin-left: 150px;
            margin-right: 150px;
            margin-top: 60px;
            text-indent: 20px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .p1and2 {
            color: #c8e1e1;
        }

        .p3 {
            color: #c8e1e1;
        }

        .p4 {
            color: #c8e1e1;
            margin-bottom: 80px;
        }

        footer {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 80px;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .ftr {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            color: #c8e1e1;
        }

        img.center {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <header class="mh-container">
        <div class="h-container">

            <h1>José María Penabad B.</h1>

            <h2 id="Abo">Abogado</h2>

            <h2 id="Att">Attorney at Law</h2>

            <h2 id="San">San Jose, Costa Rica</h2>

            <h2 id="email">jpenabad@racsa.co.cr</h2>

            <div id="scales1">
                <img src="imagesC/scales1.png" alt="scales of justice" height="140" width="140">
            </div>

            <div id="scales2">
                <img src="imagesC/scales2.png" alt="scales of justice" height="140" width="140">
            </div>

            <div id="flag1">
                <img class="f1radius" src="imagesC/flag1.png" alt="flag" height="40" width="70">
            </div>

            <div id="flag2">
                <img class="f2radius" src="imagesC/flag2.png" alt="flag" height="40" width="70">
            </div>

        </div><!--close h-container-->

    </header>


    <!--Roman Columns-->
    <div class="content">

        <div id="col_topleft">
            <img src="column.jpg" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
        </div>

        <div id="col_topright">
            <img src="column.jpg" alt="column" height="420" width="60">
        </div>

        <div id="col_bottleft">
            <img src="column.jpg" alt="column" height="596" width="60">
        </div>

        <div id="col_bottright">
            <img src="column.jpg" alt="column" height="596" width="60">
        </div>

        <div id="scroll1">
            <img src="imagesC/scroll1.png" alt="scroll" height="80" width="700">
        </div>

        <div id="scroll2">
            <img class="radius" src="imagesC/scroll2.png" alt="scroll" height="80" width="385">
        </div>

        <h3 class=toph3>Please Allow Me To Introduce Myself.</br>I'm a man of wealth and taste !</h3>

        <p class="p1and2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque, inventore, natus obcaecati debitis facilis quos ipsum libero quidem voluptatum tenetur laboriosam perspiciatis! Unde optio aliquid cum alias similique nobis cupiditate.
            Temporibus, itaque, nobis, quaerat omnis amet ipsam provident sed ea incidunt minus consectetur corporis. Aliquam, excepturi ipsum similique ad tenetur quas labore ipsam cupiditate dolorem odit inventore laborum ea. Ut!
        </p>

        <p class="p1and2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis, et saepe. Exercitationem, perferendis, nemo quo itaque unde vel consectetur est sequi recusandae eum cum assumenda non sapiente excepturi quas odio.
            Sit, alias, ea quibusdam adipisci aperiam officia a aliquam dolorum id culpa animi distinctio nisi voluptates repellat vel? Debitis, praesentium recusandae iusto a quis ducimus libero voluptates porro aperiam earum.
        </p>

        <h3 class=both3>Beinvenido !</h3>


        <p class="p3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, et dolorem cumque odit maxime unde sapiente nesciunt in quo vitae temporibus consequuntur voluptas dolor ipsum repellendus alias nam quia at?
            Ratione, at, sed, quisquam, repellat reiciendis laudantium consequatur molestiae adipisci vero tempora ab saepe iste doloribus ad earum rem mollitia quidem soluta laborum magni! Excepturi enim qui odio ut rerum.
        </p>

        <p class="p4">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, et dolorem cumque odit maxime unde sapiente nesciunt in quo vitae temporibus consequuntur voluptas dolor ipsum repellendus alias nam quia at?
            Ratione, at, sed, quisquam, repellat reiciendis laudantium consequatur molestiae adipisci vero tempora ab saepe iste doloribus ad earum rem mollitia quidem soluta laborum magni! Excepturi enim qui odio ut rerum.
        </p>

    </div><!--close content div-->

    <div>
        <footer>

            <p class="ftr"><strong>Copyright 2017 &copy; All Rights Reserved</strong></p>

            <div>
                <img src="imagesC/ALMA.png" alt="ALMA" height="22" width="220" class="center" />
            </div>

        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Chrome**[image]

**Firefox**
[image]

**IE**
[image]

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you have put into trying to help me. Thank you.  Unfortunately I am still having the same problem. It seems I am unable to post screen shots, as I have less than 10 reputation points.

Comment: do you see the problem you are having from my screenshot?

Comment: In your screen captures the images you used to for the columns appear to go all the way to the bottom of the footer. Whereas mine in Chrome stop at the top of the footer. Also there is an image called ' scroll2 ' that I don't see a broken link to in your captures. It also should sit right on top of the footer.  Which it does for me in Chrome.

Comment: Just saw your comment, No I a don't see the same problem.

Comment: I hope I did things things correct in trying to apply your solution. I placed all my CSS inside the style tags in my index file along with my HTML.  This is confusing to me since all my CSS is still in my style sheet.

Comment: I'm trying to type as fast as I can right now. What info do you need ?

Comment: My email is  thediablosays@yahoo.com   Thanks